# How do I set up a route to remove a user from a team that has_many :users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I basically have the following relationship between my `team` and `user` models. 

 `# team.rb
 has_many :users`

While on the team#show page, I have a table of users and I want to include a link to remove each user from the team. I'm currently unsure of how I should setup the route since I've never encountered it before.

Would love some help with this :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your routes.rb.

```
resources :teams do
 resources :users
end
```

You will get routes scoped by `team_id`

Eg: for delete

```
delete /teams/:team_id/users/:id
```

You can also have users as individual resource

resources :users

you will get the route as

```
delete user users/:id
```

And in your users controller, add destroy action

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "User deleted successfully"
    else
     flash[:error] = "Problem deleting user"
    end
    redirect_to teams_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I got this instead of having ```/:id``` at the end
```DELETE /teams/:team_id/users(.:format)```

Comment: @GuoXiangTan: what do you get when you do `rake routes`?

Comment: My bad :P I was typing ```resource``` instead of ```resources``` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to delete the users, just remove their affiliations with the their current team.  I'm also assuming you want a player to only be part of 1 team at a time. Just have each link next to a team member link to the User#update

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
  def update
    user = User.where(:id => params[:id])
    user.update(params[])
    user.save
  end
end
```

As long as you said `resources :users` in your routes.rb file, you can just use the default update route it makes for you.  Just make sure you pass it the new params you want (it will just be nil if you want to remove a foreign key).  You can use it to add, remove, or update any column in your model.